# Convert HTML symbols and HTML names to HTML number using Java

Tags: java, xml, htmlspecialchars

I have an XML which contains many special symbols like ® (HTML number &#174) etc.
and HTML names like &atilde (HTML number ã) etc.

I am trying to replace these HTML symbols and HTML names with corresponding HTML number using Java. For this, I first converted XML file to string and then used replaceAll method as:

```
File fn = new File("myxmlfile.xml");
String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(fn);
content = content.replaceAll("®", "&\#174");
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(fn, content);
```

But this is not working.

Can anyone please tell how to do it.

Thanks !!!

Comment: What is not working? Paste the error/exception, if any.

Comment: This code was not replacing symbols with HTML number. But now I am converting this xml file into document then replacing by getting textcontent of the document. Hence, it is working now.

Answer (score 2):

The signature for the replaceAll method is:

```
public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)
```

You have to be careful that your first parameter is a valid regular expression.  The Java [Pattern](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class describes the constructs used in a Java regular expression.

Based on what I see in the Pattern class description, I don't see what's wrong with:

```
content = content.replaceAll("®", "&\#174");
```

You could try:

```
content = content.replaceAll("\\p(®)", "&\#174");
```

and see if that works better.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but my problem solved on converting xml into document and then performing the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that \# is a valid escape sequence.
BTW, what's wrong with "&#174" ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want HTML numbers try first escaping for XML.

Use [EscapeUtils from Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#StringEscapeUtils%28%29).

Java may have trouble dealing with it, so first I prefere to escape Java, and after that XML or HTML.

```
    String escapedStr= StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(yourString);
    escapedStr= StringEscapeUtils.escapeXML(yourString);
    escapedStr= StringEscapeUtils.escapeHTML(yourString);
```